# WCF endpoint configurations to use in Asp.Net error

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have some WCF services hosted inside an Asp.Net application which are used for returning data via Ajax.  IIS (6.0) has Windows Authentication turned on and Anonymous access turned off.  I have tried various combinations of settings under the service model section of the web.config but cannot seem to get the right combination.  The error I keep getting is:

Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

Here's my web.config

```
<configuration>  <system.web>    <authentication mode="Windows"/>   </system.web>

  <location path="~/Services">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>   </location>

  <system.serviceModel>    

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>  

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="default">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>

    <services>  
      <service name="WFS.SIG.Client.USM.Web.Services.Desks">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WFS.SIG.Client.USM.Web.Services.Desks"/>
      </service>
    </services>  

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Any help in clarifying this issue would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shiraz Bhaiji - If you look at the web.config, it is using "TransportCredentialOnly" for mode.  It turns out if you have Windows Authentication turned on and Anonymous disabled, you need to change clientCredentialType to "Ntlm".

Answer (score 0):

Your security setting in web.config is Transport only:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
```

This means that it is encrypted during transport but the request is anonymous. You must therefore have anonymous authentication turned on in IIS.